# Unable to enable Security Health Analytics under GCP Security Command Centre

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform

I have enabled Security Health Analytics under the **Security Command Center Standard** at Org level; however, I am still prompted to enable it on the Vulnerabilities page.

[image: Security Command Centre Dashboard]

I have tried multiple times to enable/disable **Security Health Analytics**, but I still encounter the same prompt.

Has anyone else faced a similar issue? How did you manage to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCP Support confirmed it was a misconfiguration on their backend, and they fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally caused by a lack of permissions. Make sure that you have the following permissions:

- `roles/securitycenter.admin`, or
- `roles/resourcemanager.organizationAdmin`

Additionally, the service account used by CSCC must have the role:

- `roles/securitycenter.serviceAgent`

Comment: All of these have been configured. I have raised a case with GCP Support for this issue,

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. What was the outcome?